# YUI attach event to dynamic content

Tags: yui

I Jquery, one can attach/register an event for dynamic content( which loaded later, through ajax) through [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method. Is there anything similar in YUI

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  live() is basically one approach for event delegation.  YUI has the delegate method for this purpose: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/event/#delegate

Comment: YUI 2 version: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Event.html#method_delegate